# how to use update_attributes in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade

Currently I am upgrading my application from rails 3.2 to rails 4.
Got the following  error.

```
ArgumentError (argument out of range):
```

This error occured because of following line of code

```
@lease.update_attributes(params[:lease])
```

I tried by update that also throw the same error.
Is update_attributes removed from rails 4.how to use this?

code:

```
def terms_build_methods
  if @lease.blank?
    @lease = params[:current_lease_id].present? ? Lease.find_by_id(params[:current_lease_id].to_i) : Lease.create(params[:lease])
  else
    @lease.update(lease_params)
  end
  Lease.update_lease_occupancy_type(@lease)
  Lease.update_lease_status(@lease)
end

private

def lease_params
  params.require(:lease).permit!
end
```

Comment: No, its not removed. What's coming in `params[:lease]` ?

Comment: a) What is coming in `params[:lease]`
b) What does the leases table look like (in your schema file or SQL)

Answer (score 8):

Just use `@lease.update(lease_params)` this and also in the controller add a private method

```
def lease_params
  params.require(:lease).permit!
end
```

Comment: yes after updating your code also throwing the same error(added privATE method in controller also).

Comment: your if condition for create is wrong and also not sure if the 
  Lease.update_lease_occupancy_type(@lease) and Lease.update_lease_status(@lease) method have some problem. it will be nice if you comment all the other code except @lease.update(lease_params)... and how could you get the @lease object i have not seen this object is initialized any where in the code.

Comment: no issue with other line of codes.i have checked by removing @lease.update(lease_params) code.if i remove that its going for next level.

Comment: how you are getting @lease variable ?

Comment: its instance variable which is available where they called 
def terms_build_methods
I checked by printing that.its printing no issue with that

Comment: Then i am not sure what's the issue with the code . need to check the whole code base if it is in public git then i can check and let you know. what ever i have posted is the standard approach which works every time.

Comment: okey thanks for your valuable time.code was not in public repo.i will try myself.once again thanks

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh: while OP will certainly have to use strong_params in their controller, failing to do so doesn't throw an ArgumentError.  It throws `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes`

Comment: @ABMagil Not sure about your problem. can you explain?

Comment: OP's question seems to be related to why they are getting an argument error.  Your answer has two parts: 1) Changing `update_attributes` to `update` which isn't a change, since they are aliased methods.  2) Changing `params[:lease]` to use the strong_params form.  This won't change the value of any of the arguments, so it won't affect an "argument out of range" error.

Answer (score -2):

In Rails 4 we can expect to update_attribute() to be renamed. The new method name is called update_column(). See this commit for more information.

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a7f4b0a1231bf3c65db2ad4066da78c3da5ffb01

Comment: the question is discussing `update_attributes` not `update_attribute`.  These are different methods (in fact the confusion here is exactly what the commit you linked is trying to resolve)